# HAproxy - How to match a given URL without any paths allowed?

Tags: url, match, acl, haproxy

I want forward traffic using an exactly matching URL e.g. `test.example.com` with a ACL rule in the given frontend. When `test.example.com\path` it should move to another backend. My setup is a little bit more complicated, means just specify an acl matching for the path for the given backend does not work for me.

ACL logic: use backend IF acl_match_exact_url FOR EVERYTHING ELSE acl_use_other_backend.

Is there a way only to **match** the URL via ACL?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want an ACL that can match by host header and/or path.  You can do that several ways, for example you can match the [req.hdr(host)](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#7.3.6-req.hdr) and [path](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#7.3.6-path) separately like so:

```
acl match_path path /path
acl match_host req.hdr(host) test.example.com
use_backend backend_one if match_path match_host
default_backend backend_two
```

You can also do this with [base](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#7.3.6-base), which concatenates both host and path into one sample, e.g:

```
acl match_host_and_path base test.example.com/path
use_backend backend_one if match_host_and_path
default_backend backend_two
```